# Replacing Reoccurring Words in Java between Two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, replace

I have two arrays:

```
String common[] = {"also", "bad", "because", "but", "by", "crazy", "day", "for", "from", "good", "how", "just", "most", "no", "other", "people", "some", "speak", "speech", "strange", "talk", "them", "then", "think", "way", "what", "where", "who", "why", "with", "yes", "you"};
```

and

```
String jabber[] = {"ancient", "ballerina", "banana", "bankroll", "berserker", "birthplace", "blathering", "bouncy", "boutique", "candelabra", "cannibal", "capacitor", "circuit", "crash", "craven", "creepy", "dance", "dangerous", "daring", "dastardly", "download", "dragon", "ego", "evaluate", "feudal", "fiery", "flux", "funky", "ghostly", "glass", "gold", "grizzly", "hatch", "Hogwarts", "horn", "impure", "jump", "muscle", "near", "nicest", "omnivore", "parasite", "patronus", "punch", "salad", "savage", "seven", "shameful", "since", "slither", "sonic", "spaceship", "square", "tango", "tape", "throughout", "upon", "volcano"};
```

I have a scanner, which accepts user input, let's assume. Given a line as input, this method should be able to switch a common word with a jabberword for every occurrence for the same common word: for example, if the input is:
also also also
then, say it picks to replace also with ancient, it should say
ancient ancient ancient

**Here is my code:**

```
public static String getJabberwordyResponse(String line) {
    String[] common = {"also", "bad", "because", "but", "by", "crazy", "day", "for", "from", "good", "how", "just", "most", "no", "other", "people", "some", "speak", "speech", "strange", "talk", "them", "then", "think", "way", "what", "where", "who", "why", "with", "yes", "you"};
    String[] jabber = {"ancient", "ballerina", "banana", "bankroll", "berserker", "birthplace", "blathering", "bouncy", "boutique", "candelabra", "cannibal", "capacitor", "circuit", "crash", "craven", "creepy", "dance", "dangerous", "daring", "dastardly", "download", "dragon", "ego", "evaluate", "feudal", "fiery", "flux", "funky", "ghostly", "glass", "gold", "grizzly", "hatch", "Hogwarts", "horn", "impure", "jump", "muscle", "near", "nicest", "omnivore", "parasite", "patronus", "punch", "salad", "savage", "seven", "shameful", "since", "slither", "sonic", "spaceship", "square", "tango", "tape", "throughout", "upon", "volcano"};
    for(int i = 0; i < common.length; i++) {
        int j = (i >= jabber.length - 1) ? 0 : i;
        line.replace(common[i], jabber[i]);

    }
    return line;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve, Can you post sample input and output ?

Comment: *Thoughts?* Reduce the jibber in the [jibber jabber](https://youtu.be/Eisa5AZ20W0).

Comment: I would create a `Map` to hold the corresponding common and jabber words, and then iterate over each word in `line`, and if the `Map` `containsKey` the word, then switch it with the corresponding jabber word

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line into multiple words, and then start to check each word if contained inside `common`, if yes then replace it with the correct word inside `jabber`. After that join those worlds back to the line.

```
public static String getJabberwordyResponse(String line) {
    String[] common = {"also", "bad", "because", "but", "by", "crazy", "day", "for", "from", "good", "how", "just", "most", "no", "other", "people", "some", "speak", "speech", "strange", "talk", "them", "then", "think", "way", "what", "where", "who", "why", "with", "yes", "you"};
    String[] jabber = {"ancient", "ballerina", "banana", "bankroll", "berserker", "birthplace", "blathering", "bouncy", "boutique", "candelabra", "cannibal", "capacitor", "circuit", "crash", "craven", "creepy", "dance", "dangerous", "daring", "dastardly", "download", "dragon", "ego", "evaluate", "feudal", "fiery", "flux", "funky", "ghostly", "glass", "gold", "grizzly", "hatch", "Hogwarts", "horn", "impure", "jump", "muscle", "near", "nicest", "omnivore", "parasite", "patronus", "punch", "salad", "savage", "seven", "shameful", "since", "slither", "sonic", "spaceship", "square", "tango", "tape", "throughout", "upon", "volcano"};
    String[] worlds = line.split("\\s+"); //split line to multiple word
    for(int i = 0; i < worlds.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < common.length; j++) {
            if(common[j].equals(worlds[i])) {
                worlds[i] = jabber[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return String.join(" ", worlds);// join back the worlds to get the result
}
```